# How to draw a bar (a filled rectangle of a very small height, just like a node of shape "line")?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My current picture of a Petri net is 
[image: below]

The problem: the 'bars' (in grey) are too tall, although `minimum height=0.1mm` (seems doesn't have any effect). **Is it possible to make these grey rectangles even thinner?**

---

The code is (no need to read the whole, just look into two comments):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata,positioning,calc,patterns,petri}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]

\tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=6mm]
\tikzstyle{red place}=[place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20]
\tikzstyle{transition}=[rectangle,  % <------Can we make them thinner?
          thick,     
          draw=black!75,
          fill=black!25,
          minimum height=0.1mm,     %<------------------ this doesn't help
          minimum width=8mm,
          rounded corners]

\tikzstyle{every label}=[red]

\node [place,tokens=1] (start)                    {$start$};
\node [transition] (start_to_start_q0) [below left of=start] {};
\node [transition] (start_to_q0_ok) [below right of=start] {};

\node [place]          (q0)     [below of=start_to_start_q0]  {$q_0$};
\node [place]          (ok)     [below of=start_to_q0_ok]     {$ok$};

\node [place] (q) [below left of=q0]             {$q$};
\node [transition] (from_q_ok) [below right of=q] {};

\node [place] (qsa) [below left of=from_q_ok]           {$q_{a!!}$};
\node [place] (a) [right of=qsa]                    {$a$};
\node [transition] (from_qsa_a) [below right of=qsa] {};

\node [place] (p) [right of=a]                    {$p$};
\node [transition] (from_a_p) [below right of=a] {};

\node [place] (qend) [below of=from_qsa_a]             {$q'$};

\node [place] (pra) [below of=from_a_p]             {$p_{a??}$};
\node [transition] (from_ok_pra) [right of=pra] {};
\node [place] (pend) [right of=from_ok_pra]             {$p'$};

\path (start_to_start_q0)
  edge [pre,bend right]                (start)
  edge [post]                          (start)
  edge [post]                          (q0);

\path (start_to_q0_ok)
  edge [pre]                           (start)
  edge [post]                          (q0)
  edge [post]                          (ok);

\path (from_q_ok)
  edge [pre]                          (q)
  edge [pre]                          (ok)
  edge [post]                         (qsa)
  edge [post]                         (a);

\path (from_qsa_a)
  edge [pre]                          (qsa)
  edge [pre]                          (a)
  edge [post]                         (qend)
  edge [post]                         (ok);

\path (from_a_p)
  edge [pre]                          (a)
  edge [pre]                          (p)
  edge [post]                         (pra)
  edge [post]                         (a);

\path (from_ok_pra)
  edge [pre]                          (ok)
  edge [pre]                          (pra)
  edge [post]                         (ok)
  edge [post]                         (pend);    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry - I gave up half way through an answer. -Too much code, where only a small part is nedded, and it is not compileable. I think you need to look at `inner sep` option.

Comment: Yes - If you add `inner sep=0` to your nodes, then you can control the heigth with `minimum height`. But be aware, that the rounded corners will look strange with a very small height.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen i would accept your comment as an answer, but cannot.) rounded corners are not an issue -- i removed them. thaanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `inner sep` node option is a node padding, that insures space between node text and node border. By setting it to zero, you can control the node height with `minimum height` as wished.

This code:

```
\tikzstyle{transition}=[rectangle,
          thick,     
          draw=black!75,
          fill=black!25,
          minimum height=1mm,
          minimum width=8mm,
          rounded corners,
          inner sep=0]
```

[image: 1 mm nodes]

gives 1 mm high nodes, but the rounded corners now look odd. Maybe that is an issue for an other question.

Comment: You may use `rounded corners=.5mm` (half of `minimum height`).

Comment: Or even the shape `rounded rectangle` which needs the library `shapes.misc`. Moreover, do not use `\tikzscale`, but rather `\tikzset`: see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304)